# Ubuntu Core Snappy Touch GUI app kiosk

Tags: ubuntu-touch, gui, touchscreen, kiosk, ubuntu-core

I just learned about Ubuntu Core Snappy about 2 hours ago. I was very excited as I was thinking about making a stand alone java application that has a simple full screen touch GUI. This would be a single application full screen GUI. no desktop, kiosk. I found out that Ubuntu core "Snappy" is a terminal base interface as expected from a minimal distro. I would like to build a java application with a touch GUI interface with normal widgets like buttons and images maybe dropdowns and toggles. So far I have only found tutorials for making web server applications with this. Is there or will there be tutorials on how to make a stand alone touch app kiosk that runs local to the ubuntu core "snappy" os? Not a web server.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it is possible because you can't install `Xorg` on it. If you could, I would do the following.
1) enable automatic logging in and boot straight to command line

2) gut (keep important stuff though) the /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc file and add the following:

```
exec java -jar /path/to/jar.jar
```

3) add in the rc.local to execute `startx` on boot

This should boot into your jar on boot.
If you can pull this off let me know, because I am working on a similar project.

Answer (score 0):

This is indeed one of the possibilities, here's a [walkthrough](https://docs.google.com/document/d/14msTXe_cFulk9z4jFptEjFJzZx58b1mWU_r4VivLkfA/edit?hl=en&forcehl=1) for setting up mir and a simple QML based application and a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DJjYC_-wcSQ)

> My java knowledge is limited at best to get the other part of the question answered correctly.